# Simple HTTP POST with an anonymous type as body

Tags: c#, json, webclient, anonymous-types, dotnet-httpclient

I can't really find a working example, maybe it is because its simply not possible?

I'd like to take a C# anonymous type object like the following:

```
var postBody = new
{
   friend = new 
   {
      name = "dave",
      last ="franz"
   },
   id = "12345",
   login = "mylogin" 
};
```

and post it to my web service in a simple http POST with the following post body:

```
{
   "friend" :
   {
      "name" : "dave",
      "last" : "franz"
   },
   "id" : "12345",
   "login" : "mylogin" 
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty easy using [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json). You can get it using the nuget package manager in VS.

```
var postBody = new
{
   friend = new 
   {
      name = "dave",
      last ="franz"
   },
   id = "12345",
   login = "mylogin" 
};
var postString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postBody);
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var responseString = wc.UploadString(serviceAddress, "POST", postString);
}
```

Comment: I would have preferred a solution without having to install a nugget package, but this wasn't mentionned in my initial post, and you solution  works quite well. Thank you sir !

Comment: @guiomie : the preferred ASP.NET mvc solution uses JavaScriptSerializer, which is/was marked as obsolete (there is considerable confusion about this decision). I prefer JSON.net anyway... it's very stable and much more powerful that anything on offer in the BCL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `HttpClient client`:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "<URL>") {
  Content = JsonContent.Create(new {
    Prop = "Value"
  })
};
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```